# Fedora 19 no longer bootable

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub

I had fedora dual-booted with windows on my laptop for a while but with windows refresh grub was gone and my system directly booted windows. I booted fedora with my systems boot options and with this tutorial: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2
I reinstalled grub2 but then had my system booted into an empty grub prompt: grub>
So I found the drive containing  vmlinuz and initramfs (completely sure about thair location and versions) and tried to manually boot it but after the boot command it said:

> no suitable video mode found
>
> booting in blind mode

and nothing happened.

Such a tragedy...

I have already tried to use live disks rescue system. Funny but troubleshooting options don't apear on my laptop while they do on my desktop pc. I cant even go to boot prompt on my lenovo idepad z400 laptop.

I also tried EasyBCD so maybe I could boot it with windows but it comes up with this error:

> missing AutoNeoGrub().mbr

Now I have removed the grub prompt (don't know why) and its really hard for me to reinstall my dearly customized fedora.
If anyone knows a way to help boot it again or reinstall it keeping my files and installations I really need it.

Thanks

PS:I have already tried Boot-repair Disk but it asks me to enable the repo containing grub-efi on my fedora to reinstall the grub2 and fix the boot for me (how could i?).

Comment: Are you using UEFI, SecureBoot, or FastBoot? Also are you using LVM?

Comment: I never used any of them

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with SystemRescueCD.  They even have a webpage devoted to your problem of having to fix a broken GRUB to rescue the Linux system.

www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-Partitioning-EN-Repairing-a-damaged-Grub